# Configure Nginx to proxy pass to Gunicorn (working when I visit IP, not working when I visit domain name)

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure Nginx to proxy pass to Gunicorn. 
My django project can be found at `/home/justin/project/jobzumo`

Start by creating and opening a new server block in Nginx’s sites-available directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/jobzumo
```

Within this file I've entered the following:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name 142.93.184.125;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root /home/justin/project;
        }
        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

When I go to `142.93.184.125` I see the default django rocket ship, so I think that means everything is working. However, when I go to 'jobzumo.com' (associated domain), I see the default 'Welcome to nginx!' page.

I know I have both the IP and domain name in my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` settings and have pointed the domain nameservers at my server.  So, do I need to add this domain to this file? The tutorial I was following said either or should do the job. If adding the domain to this file is not what I have to do, can you mention that, so at least I know I'll have to start looking elsewhere. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `server_name jobzumo.com;` if you want to serve domain only on specific IP address instead of all avilable interfaces, specify it as `listen 142.93.184.125:80;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky that does work but now the opposite is happening. Django rocket ship at jobzumo.com, 'welcome to nginx' at IP. Though, maybe this is something I don't need to worry about since nobody accesses a site via IP address?

Comment: You can try `listen 80 default_server;`, if nginx complies that another server block already uses `default_server` flag, remove it from that block.

Answer (score 2):

You probably still have the default site in available sites in nginx which is causing the issue. I just had the same problem and the following two commands solved the issue:

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

if you stopped your gunicorn daemon you might need to restart it and then run the second command above it should do the trick.